# Why is this unrelated crate breaking my project?

Tags: rust

```
$ cargo build
 Downloading pear_codegen v0.0.16
 Compiling pear_codegen v0.0.16                                               
 Compiling ring v0.11.0
 error[E0023]: this pattern has 1 field, but the corresponding tuple variant has 2 fields
 --> /.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/pear_codegen-0.0.16/src/lib.rs:317:9
     |
 317 |         ExprKind::Block(block) => {
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 2 fields, found 1

 error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0023`.
error: Could not compile `pear_codegen`.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

When I try to compile my project I get an error that a crate that isn't in my cargo.toml is broken. Why is this unrelated crate breaking my project?

Comment: Note that dependencies are transitive; if your project depends on `A` which depends on `B`, then your project also depends on `B`, even if that dependency is not explicit in your Cargo.toml. This is actually one of the most important *features* of dependency management systems such as Cargo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Rust nightly, and the crate in question used to depend (in version `0.0.16`) on the perma-unstable API of the Rust compiler, which was changed by a nightly you updated to (or just installed).
The author [appears to have recently rewritten](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Pear/commit/d4f44e6b0e41887d1fdac26981aeb9872f55783f) the crate to avoid that dependency, which means further breakage should be avoided, starting with version `0.0.17` of the crate.

Answer (score 0):

```
cargo update
```

fixed the issue for me

https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Pear/issues/7

[thanks to reddit user /u/usernamedottxt](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/8m6au2/comment/dzlg6r1)